# Do something while on change is pressed with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I made some code to generate RGB colors but it works after changed but I wish to do it while changing:

```
<input type="range" id="myNumber" min="0" max="255" onchange="myFunction()" value="0" />
<input type="range" id="myNumber2" min="0" max="255" onchange="myFunction()" value="0" />
<input type="range" id="myNumber3" min="0" max="255" onchange="myFunction()" value="0" />
<p id="demo">Blalalalala</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("myNumber2").value;
    var z = document.getElementById("myNumber3").value;  
    document.getElementById("demo").style.transition = 'background 0.5s ease 0s';
    document.getElementById("demo").style.background = 'rgb('+x+','+y+','+z+')';
}
</script>
```

UPDATE!

WITH ANSWER I ADDED A FOR OPACITY AND HERE IS FULL CODE IF SOMEBODY NEEDS

```
 <p>R (Stands for red):
    <input type="range" id="myNumber" min="0" max="255" step="1" oninput="myFunction()" value="0" /></p>
    <p>G (Stands for green):
    <input type="range" id="myNumber2" min="0" max="255" step="1" oninput="myFunction()" value="0" /></p>
    <p>B (Stands for blue):
    <input type="range" id="myNumber3" min="0" max="255" step="1" oninput="myFunction()" value="0" /></p>
    <p>A (Stands for opacity):
    <input type="range" id="myNumber4" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" oninput="myFunction()" value="1" /></p>




    <p id="demo">sasasasa</p>

    <script>
    document.getElementById("demo").style.background = 'rgb(0,0,0,1)';
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("myNumber2").value;
        var z = document.getElementById("myNumber3").value; 
        var a = document.getElementById("myNumber4").value;     
        document.getElementById("demo").style.transition = 'background 0.5s ease 0s';
        document.getElementById("demo").style.background = 'rgba('+x+','+y+','+z+','+a+')';
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HTML5 [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event instead of [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event.

```html
<input type="range" id="myNumber" min="0" max="255" oninput="myFunction()" value="0" />
<input type="range" id="myNumber2" min="0" max="255" oninput="myFunction()" value="0" />
<input type="range" id="myNumber3" min="0" max="255" oninput="myFunction()" value="0" />




<p id="demo">Blalalalala</p>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("myNumber2").value;
    var z = document.getElementById("myNumber3").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").style.transition = 'background 0.5s ease 0s';
    document.getElementById("demo").style.background = 'rgb(' + x + ',' + y + ',' + z + ')';
  }
</script>
```

Check [browser compatibility of input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: If you appreciate this answer, how about you [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.

Answer (score 2):

`onchange` should only be triggered when the user releases the mouse. To get continuous updates, you should use the `oninput` event, which will capture live updates in Firefox, Safari and Chrome, both from the mouse and the keyboard.

However, `oninput` is not supported in IE10, so your best bet is to combine the two event handlers, like this:

```
<input type="range" id="myNumber" min="0" max="255" onchange="myFunction()" oninput="myFunction()" value="0" />
```

Comment: [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-event) states otherwise. IE9 has partial support. IE10 has full

Comment: I think this answer is better because it explained the difference between `onchange` and `oninput`